# What is the correct way to use prompt() inside an useEffect in React.StrictMode so it doesn't run twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

React.StrictMode renders the page twice to debug purposes. I have a prompt() in a page,
which is running twice because of this, and I've been trying to work around it, since I'd like to keep StrictMode.

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
useEffect(() => {
      let identified = false;
      if (!identified) {
        let pName = prompt("Insert name");
        setPlayerName(pName);
      }
    return () => {
      identified = true;
    }
   }, [])
```

Also tried this:

```
const [playerName, setPlayerName] = useState('');
useEffect(() => {
      if (!playerName) {
        let pName = prompt("Insira name");
        setPlayerName(pName);
      }
   }, [])
```

And this...:

```
const [playerName, setPlayerName] = useState('');
useEffect(() => {
      if (!playerName) {
        let pName = prompt("Insira name");
        return () => {
          setPlayerName(pName);;
        }
      }
   }, [])
```

but can't get it right. What's the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/18) you can find info on how to do this:

> Effects that should only run once can use a ref.

```
const didLogRef = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  // In this case, whether we are mounting or remounting,
  // we use a ref so that we only log an impression once.
  if (didLogRef.current === false) {
    didLogRef.current = true;

    SomeTrackingAPI.logImpression();
  }
}, []);
```

In your scenario:

```
const didPromptRef= useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (didPromptRef.current === false) {
    didLogRef.current = true;
    const pName = prompt("Insert name");
    setPlayerName(pName);
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Does this work in his case?